# spring webflux FilePart how to validate mime type?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

Given the controller mapping below, I wonder how to validate that the provided file is an image with maximum file size.

```
@PostMapping("/users/avatar")
suspend fun uploadAvatar(@RequestPart("file") filePartMono: Mono<FilePart>) {
  filePartMono.map{ part -> part.content().map{ it.asInputStream().readAllBytes() }
    .map { it /* ??? */ }
  }
  // ...
}
```

On the non-reactive stack I did it like this:

```
uploadAvatar(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    String contentType = file.getContentType().toLowerCase();
    List<String> valid = Arrays.asList("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png");
    if (file.isEmpty() || !valid.contains(contentType)) {
        throw new UploadException("Invalid image format or empty file", HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
    }
    if (file.getSize() > IMAGE_MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
        throw new UploadException("Image too big (max " + (IMAGE_MAX_FILE_SIZE / 1000) + " kB )", HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
    }
    try {
        // try to read file as image to ensure it is an image
        ImageIO.read(file.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UploadException("Invalid image", HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
    }

    try {
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        userService.storeAvatar(bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UploadException("Could not store image", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

but FilePart does not provide the same API (e.g. contentType).

How can I obtain contentType and file size from the `FilePart`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FilePart` have headers which you can access like this.

```kotlin
@PostMapping(value = ["/upload"], consumes = [MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE])
suspend fun upload(@RequestPart(name = "file") file: Mono<FilePart>) {
    val filePart = file.awaitFirstOrNull() ?: throw Exception()

    println(filePart.headers().contentType)
    println(filePart.headers().contentLength)
}
```

However, just relying on `Header` for `Content-Type` is not a good idea I think. So, you can use `Tika` library for type detection. Considering you are using `Gradle` you can do this.

In your `build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
implementation("org.apache.tika:tika-core:1.26")
```

However, `Tika` detect is blocking call so you will need to do something like this.

```kotlin
@PostMapping(value = ["/upload"], consumes = [MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE])
suspend fun upload(@RequestPart(name = "file") file: Mono<FilePart>) : Response {
    val filePart = file.awaitFirstOrNull() ?: throw Exception()
    val inputStream = filePart.content().awaitFirst().asInputStream()
    val detectedFileTye = getFilePartFileType(filePart.filename(), inputStream)
    // ...
}

private suspend fun getFilePartFileType(fileName: String, inputStream: InputStream): String? = coroutineScope {
    val mimeTypeDeferred = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        Tika().detect(inputStream, fileName)
    }
    mimeTypeDeferred.await()
}
```

Something along that line..

Comment: The only thing I do not understand is the return type `FileType?` of the private helper function. Which package does it refer to? the `mimeTypeDeferred` is of Type `Deferred<String>`.

Comment: Oops sorry it should have been `String` bad copy/paste. I am using `FileType` but its a custom object not relevant here.

Comment: Thanks! I learned a lot. Could you also let me know how you get the actual `ByteArray`? From what I read tika will reset the inputstream so we can reuse it and I now would use the same pattern `val bytes = coroutineScope { val bytesDeferred = async(Dispatchers.IO) { inputStream.readAllBytes() } bytesDeferred.await() }`

Comment: Yeah that’s one way to do it. In my case there was no need to use ByteArray.